# Webpages loading slowly at start

Tags: domain-name-system, http, https

I'm having an issue in my organization where webpages are slow to load when first requested.  In a Chrome browser we typically see the "waiting for *site*" or "establishing secure connection" messages in the lower corner.  This typically lasts for 5-10 seconds and then the page loads quickly like normal.

A few observations on this:

- Have been noticing it off and on for a couple of weeks now.
- Happened out of the blue.
- Happens with all browsers.
- Happens with both HTTP and HTTPS requests.

One more thing that I find to be very odd is that it seems to only be affecting our Mac devices running OSX.  We have several that are bootcamped with Windows 7 and have no problem at all on these.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

***EDIT***

Results from Chrome Connectivity Diagnostics:
[Diagnostic Report Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSKN5.png)

```
> SUMMARY Test Name: Google Websites HTTP Latency Test Test ID: 9 
> Test result: Problem detected
> 
> Tue May 16 2017 11:02:50 GMT-0500 (CDT) - HTTP response # / time received (microtimestamp) / elapsed time(ms): 2 / 1494950570671 / 7422
> Tue May 16 2017 11:02:50 GMT-0500 (CDT) - Total HTTP response time (ms): 22414 
> Tue May 16 2017 11:02:50 GMT-0500 (CDT) - Total number of HTTP requests: 3 
> Tue May 16 2017 11:02:50 GMT-0500 (CDT) - Average HTTP response time (ms): 7471.33
```

Comment: Have you used the developer tools, or other browser plugins to look at a breakdown of dns, tcp, http times for each object on your pages?  Do your macs have different dns or proxy servers set by dhcp?   Does your site do different things with different user-agents?

Comment: Aaron- I edited my post to include the results of a Chrome Connectivity tool.  All machines are using the same DNS server.  We are also using a content filter.

Comment: If you bypass your content filter, do you get the same results?  Have you had an admin check the logs on the filter (proxy, I assume)?